# Warning on in_array() for Wrong datatype for second argument, when working with strings

Tags: php, arrays, debugging

Im using this code to read out of a file, Im getting an error Warning on in_array() for Wrong datatype for second argument.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $SongToAdd = stripslashes($_POST['SongName']) . "\n";
  $ExistingSongs = array();

  if (file_exists("SongOrganizer/songs.txt") && filesize("SongOrganizer/songs.txt") > 0) {
    $ExistingSongs = file("SongOrganizer/songs.txt");
  }
}

if (in_array($SongToAdd, $ExistingSongs)) {
  echo "<p>The song you entered already exists!<br />\n";
  echo "Your song was not added to the list.</p>";
```

The text file contains:

```
Bang Bang
Doctor
Hello
Ice Cream Man
Show Me
Doctor
```

Comment: What's the value of `$ExistingSongs` when `$_POST['submit']` is NOT set? In other words: Can you be sure that `$ExistingSongs` is an array when you hand it to in_array()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what about the first time your page loads? If `$_POST['submit']` is not set then `$ExistingSongs` will be `null`. `in_array` is right to complain about that.

If you were developing with all errors enabled -- done with `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT)` or through `php.ini` -- then you 'd also have gotten a notice about `$ExistingSongs` being an undefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

If `$_POST['submit']` variable is not set, `$ExistingSongs` variable remains undefined, that can cause a warning.

Answer (score -1):

stripslashes expects a string as input, and outputs a string: http://php.net/stripslashes

$SongToAdd is a string when you call `in_array()`, hence your error.

Comment: That's just fine since the signature of in_array() is `bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )`